# Is this a second grade system?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics

There are systems that are obviously of second grade, such as:

$$x^2 + y =  1$$
$$y = x - 1$$

The definition of an n-th grade system is:

> The grade of a system is the product of the grade of all the equations inside it.

In the above system, the grade is $2 * 1 = 2$

But let me show you another system:

$$x ^ {(4/3)} + y = 8$$
$$x ^ {(6/4)} - 2y = 1$$

I apply the definition above and get:

$$ grade = 4 / 3 * 6 / 4 = 2 $$

So the nasty looking system with fractional exponents is just a second grade system like the easy peasy one at the top? If so how can I solve it simply?

Comment: How do you define the grade of an equation?

Comment: @CameronBuie the grade of an equation is the grade of the highest graded polynomial inside it.

Comment: I think grade == degree but the latter is preferable, right?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [your comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432436/is-this-a-second-grade-system/1432451#comment2918156_1432436), your definition of an equation's *grade* seems to be that of [polynomial degree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial). If so, an equation with non-integer exponents has no grade, so the latter system has no grade.

Comment: Dear @downvoter: please help me improve this post, if you feel it has specific problems.

Comment: Basically you are saying that my definition of degree (grade) can only be applied on integer exponents?

Comment: It seems that way, unless there's more to your definition of grade. In fact it only makes sense for positive integer exponents.

Comment: It is sensible, in fact if a system of degree n has n solutions, n **must** be integer, as 1/2 or 7/12 of a solution do not make any sense

Comment: Well, a degree $n$ system need not have $n$ solutions. For example, a degree $1$ system may have $0,1,$ or infinitely-many solutions.

Comment: I meant equation, about the system you are right, think `x = 1` `x = 0` no way to solve that, 0 solutions.

Comment: Well, even a degree $n$ equation needn't have only $n$ solutions. Consider $x=y.$

Comment: x = y is a system in two unknows and one equation, not a plain equation

Comment: What do you mean by "plain" equation?

Comment: one unknown only

Comment: In that case, yes. Univariate degree $n$ polynomials have $n$ zeroes, up to multiplicity.

Comment: Still, for example, the degree of each equation in your first system is finite, but each equation has infinitely-many solutions (though the system, itself, has only two).

Comment: Sorry for my sloppy vocabulary, I should be more precise